# How to continuously monitor any activity that comes into foreground

Tags: android, android-activity, service, foreground

I want my application to continuously listen to any activity that comes in foreground. I have a code to know which activity is in foreground, but my question is how do i continuously monitor in my application

Code :

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
  ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
  Log.d(WebServiceHelper.TAG, "CURRENT Activity ::" + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName()+"   Package Name :  "+componentInfo.getPackageName());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should implement using BroadcastReceiver if Android provides any such kind of notification on task/activity change, else you will need to launch a Service which checks the current activity/task after some duration you set.